# Redirect to page navigated from, after submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, submit

I'm working on a web project in Visual Studio 2012, using ASP.NET MVC and C#.

I've a `ResultController` where you can add, delete or edit results Objects (--> result of a `SportsEvent`). On **several *other* pages** I've a **link** to the **`Add` method** of the `ResultController`. But after I submit a result on the `Add` page, I'm **redirected to** the ***index*** page of the controller.

Here is my code of the `ResultController`s `Add` method:

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.EventId = new SelectList(db.Events, "EventId", "Name");
            ViewBag.AthleteId = new SelectList(db.Athletes, "AthleteId", "Name");
            ViewBag.MeetingId = new SelectList(db.Meetings, "MeetingId", "Name");
            ViewBag.StudentId = new SelectList(db.Students, "StudentId", "Name");
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Result/Create

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Result result)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Results.Add(result);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

ViewBag.EventId = new SelectList(db.Events, "EventId", "Name", result.EventId);
ViewBag.AthleteId = new SelectList(db.Athletes, "AthleteId", "Name", result.AthleteId);
ViewBag.MeetingId = new SelectList(db.Meetings, "MeetingId", "Name", result.MeetingId);
ViewBag.StudentId = new SelectList(db.Students, "StudentId", "Name", result.StudentId);
            return View(result);
        }
```

**What I want to achieve**
If the add succeeds I want to be **redirected** to the **page where I *originally came from***.

I.e. if I click on a "addResult" link on **page "x"**, I want to be **redirected to page "x"**, after the submit of the result.

How can I realize this?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
RedirectToAction("Index");
```

You could use something like:

```
return new RedirectResult(Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri);
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to help. After submit, the page is refreshed. So in fact it redirects me from the [HttpPost] "Create" action back to the normal "Create" action of the controller

Comment: Oh I see - I thought you were submitting from another page - sorry.  I think you'll need to maintain a variable in the querystring (or session / some other state storage mechanism id you don't want to pollute your url).